# Qt Icons won't load after static build

Tags: windows, qt, resources, icons, toolbar

After building Qt statically (`configure -static`) and running `mingw32-make sub-src` and running qmake on my project (build->run qmake) and rebuilding it, the exe is fully stand-alone (and huge) but the icons won't load anymore. The icons are in a .qrc file and im loading them by this method:

```
QIcon icon(":/Icons/icon.ico");
this->setWindowIcon(icon);
```

Comment: in the code example the variable names are wrong.  You create a variable named `Pizza` and the set using a variable named `icon`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtplugin.html#Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins